# Solving Complex Quadratics containing Conjugate Imaginary Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been trying to solve the equation: $z^2 + 2(z*) + 1 = 0$, where $(z*)$ is the complex conjugate of the complex number $z$, where $z \in \mathbb C$.

How do I interpret, and then solve this equation? Can I factorise for the real roots, and how do I find the complex roots?

Thanks all!!

Comment: Why not write $z=a+bi$ for $a,b\in \mathbb R$, expand, and set up two equations, one for the real part, one for the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

The direct way would be to write $z=x+iy$ for reals $x,y$. Given equation becomes
$$(x^2-y^2+2ixy)+2(x-iy)+1=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^2-y^2+2x+1)+i(2xy-2y)=0$$

On equating real and imaginary parts,
$$2y(x-1)=0$$

and

$$(x+1)^2-y^2=0$$

Can you solve these two simultaneously?

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much